# Cost of solving a matrix equation using the FFT

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, matrices, numerical-algorithms, fourier-transform

I am trying to calculate

$$V = (H^TH+I)^{-1} U$$

where $H\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ is a circulant convolution matrix corresponding to a convolution kernel $h$, and $U\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. The computation of $V$ can be done using the FFT algorithm.

I am confused about the computational complexity of using the FFT for this kind of problem. I will be most grateful if you could provide some suggestions or ideas for solving this problem. Thank you.

Comment: yes, $H$ is a circulant matrix and $H^TH$ is also circulant. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $m \times m$ symmetric matrix $\rm H^{\top} H$ is [circulant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), then its spectral decomposition is

$$\rm H^{\top} H = Q \Lambda Q^*$$

where the eigenvalues of $\rm H^{\top} H$ are given by the [Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) (DFT) of the first row of $\rm H^{\top} H$, and where the eigenvalue matrix is

$$\rm Q =  \frac{1}{\sqrt m} \, F_m$$

where $\rm F_m$ is the $m \times m$ Fourier matrix. Hence,

$$\rm H^{\top} H + I_m = Q \Lambda Q^* + I_m = Q \Lambda Q^* + Q Q^* = Q \, (\Lambda + I_m) \, Q^*$$

and

$$\rm  \left( H^{\top} H + I_m \right)^{-1} U = Q \, (\Lambda + I_m)^{-1} \, Q^* U = \frac 1m \, F_m \, (\Lambda + I_m)^{-1} \, F_m^* U$$

The [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) (FFT) algorithm can now be used to factor the Fourier matrix $\rm F_m$ and its Hermitian transpose. What is the cost?

- Computing $\Lambda$ requires one DFT of length $m$. Using the FFT, that costs $O (m \log (m))$.
- Computing $\rm F_m^* U$ requires $n$ DFTs of length $m$. Using the FFT, that costs $O (n \, m \log (m))$.
- Multiplying $\rm (\Lambda + I_m)^{-1}$ and $\rm F_m^* U$ costs $m$ additions and $m \, n$ divisions.
- Computing $\rm F_m \, (\Lambda + I_m)^{-1} \, F_m^* U$ requires $n$ DFTs of length $m$. Using the FFT, that costs $O (n \, m \log (m))$.
- Dividing $\rm F_m \, (\Lambda + I_m)^{-1} \, F_m^* U$ by $m$ costs $m \, n$ divisions.

Thus, the total cost is $O (n \, m \log (m))$.

---

#### References

- Robert M. Gray, [Toeplitz and circulant matrices: a review](https://ee.stanford.edu/%7Egray/toeplitz.html).
- [Complex matrices; fast Fourier transform](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/positive-definite-matrices-and-applications/complex-matrices-fast-fourier-transform-fft/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses3.2sum.pdf), MIT 18.06SC Linear Algebra, Fall 2011.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer and kind help.